# Why passing exception as e doesn't work, while explicitely does?

Tags: python

I'm catching an exception and I want to pass it further. I've tried this the 2 following ways:

```
except exceptions.MyException as e:
  raise exceptions.MyException(message=e.message)
```

and:

```
except exceptions.MyException as e:
  raise e(message=e.message)
```

further, I catch it as this:

```
except ArticleNotAcceptable as e:
  Messages.flash(e.message)
```

While the first version works fine, the second doesn't - it causes `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'` that doesn't tell me much. Can anyone please explain to me why?

Comment: What should the second do? In particular, what would you expect the expression `e(...)` to resolve to? Calling an exception instance like a function doesn't make sense to me. BTW: Please stop writing "doesn't work" without giving actual detail of what it does and how you come to that conclusion.

Comment: That is as asking why `int(12)` works, while `12(12)` doesn't.

Comment: BTW: Please submit your code for review on codereview.stackexchange.com. Apart from the technical problems here, I have a feeling you are not using exceptions properly. For example, catching one of type X (or derived) and then throwing one of type X (not derived) in reaction to that seems wrong.

Comment: I added the info about the error. Thank you for pointing that out. Thank you for your support, but I really don't think sarcasm is needed here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`exceptions.MyException` is a class.  `e` is an instance of MyException.  You can call the class to get another instance of MyException.  You cannot call an instance to get another instance.

Comment: Doesn't that depend on the instance, which we know pretty much nothing about?

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly the information I was missing.

Comment: @KellyBundy In a clause that begins with `except SomeException as e:`, we know that `e` is an instance of `SomeException`.  It would be abnormal for `e` to be callable.  In any case, one can `print(dir(e))` in the following suite to find out the attributes of `e`.

Comment: Abnormal but not impossible. They also said *"it causes `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'`"*, and I see no connection between `e` not being callable and that.

Answer (score 2):

If you "want to pass it further",

```
except exceptions.MyException:
    raise
```

is sufficient. You don't need the `as e` unless you have some other handling of the `MyException` instance before re-raising it.

Like others have said, most people presume that `e(e.message)` would fail with an error that `e` cannot be invoked, because it is an instance of `MyException` and not a method. However, we have not seen the full class definition for `MyException`.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Terrys answer:

If you want to pass the same exception along, you can just write raise without parameters.

```py
try:
    # stuff
except exceptions.MyException as e:
    print(f"Re-thrhowing exception {str(e)}") # or something else here
    raise
```